detect browser in html produced from quarto
I need to detect the browser name in an html file produced from a quarto qmd file containing R code.
In fact, when the browser is Firefox, another html file should be opened.
How can this be achieved?

Maybe this brings you into the right direction: navigator.userAgent gives you information about the browser.
---
output: html
---

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var browserName = "Unknown Browser";

    if (userAgent.indexOf("chrome") > -1) {
        browserName = "Chrome";
    } else if (userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
        browserName = "Firefox";
    }  else if (userAgent.indexOf("edge") > -1) {
        browserName = "Edge";
    }

    document.getElementById("browser-info").textContent = "Current Browser: " + browserName;
});
</script>

# Print the browser name

```{=html}
<p id="browser-info"></p>
```


